# magento links for sub pages with multiple currencies

Tags: magento

i'm trying to find a way to link to a subpage within my magento site but at the same time change the currency:

www.example.com shows my homepage with GBP
www.example.com/directory/currency/switch/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5pbnRlcm5ldHZvaXBwaG9uZS5jby51ay8,/currency/USD shows my homepage with USD

is there a way to show for example www.example.com/subpage.html with USD??

this is mainly for me to use in an adwords campaign in the US so users will see their own currency on the click through

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain USD, GBP and maybe EUR pricelists. Then have three websites set to the different currencies with the base URL the same for all of them. Then in index.php you need to use GeoIP (in Apache or PHP) to set the store code. You will also need to set the no store code in URLs and remove the website switcher from your templates. In that way your store will always show your chosen prices/currencies. Manually converting prices rather than converting on the fly will enable you to have price points, e.g. $6.95 rather than $6.13 and you can also 'absorb' shipping prices in those prices. The locale settings will also be easier - 'cart' for USD store and 'basket' for over here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for the response however thats not what were trying to do, if a customer heads directly to the website they will always see GBP and that is fine as its a english company, the only thing we need to do is have a link from our adwords

e.g....
English advert goes to GBP page
Same advert written in German goes to the same page but displays Euro's
Same advert but displayed in america goes to the same page but displays USD

Only 1 store, 1 price list, just wondering if there is a way to set which currency with the URL (as above with the homepage)

Comment: The above solution will do that for you. The three websites sit on the same URL but GeoIP decides what gets shown. A simple switch/case construct based on country code with a default of GBP for countries not specifically targeted.

Comment: my concern is it seems a long way round & will result in having to maintain 3 pricelists & 3 sets of products when it seems the code already exists within magento.

Comment: If you are serious about selling outside of Blighty then you will be prepared to maintain pricelists that aren't randomly converted. You will need a spreadsheet of prices and some cell macros to round up/down to price points. Importing these prices takes no longer than importing the one set, if you know what you are doing. You will also be able to fine tune what products you sell and where, e.g. some products that airlines consider 'toxic chemicals' might not be on the U.S. pricelist. Anyway, try it.